# Comparison of strftime() return value does not work

Tags: sqlite, comparison, strftime

The sqlite alias is not working properly

```
SELECT *,strftime('%s', `created_at`) AS `created_at_timestamp` FROM `sales` WHERE `created_at_timestamp` >= 1607966400 ORDER BY `created_at` DESC
```

This gives results even though the results should be 0
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#sort_order) says:

> An INTEGER or REAL value is less than any TEXT or BLOB value.

The return value of `strftime()` is a string. If you want to compare it against a number, [convert](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#castexpr) it into a number first.